# API function returns undefined on load but works on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that is currently tied to a button. When clicking the button all the data I need works perfectly fine. However if I use Jquery to call that function on window load I am received undefined. From the searches I have done I think it has something to do with Async but that is over my head honestly. Here is what I have written:

```js
var latitude;
var longitude; 
var temperature;
var currentTemp;

function GetWeather() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", `https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}`, true);
  xhttp.onload = function (e) {
    if (xhttp.readyState === 4) {
      if (xhttp.status === 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        temperature = response.main.temp;
        document.getElementById("city-text").innerHTML = "City: " + response.name;
        document.getElementById("skies-text").innerHTML =  "Skies: " + response.weather[0].main + " - " + response.weather[0].description;
        document.getElementById("skies-icon").innerHTML =  "<img src='" + response.weather[0].icon + "'>";
        document.getElementById("temperature-text").innerHTML =  "Temperature: " + temperature + "C";
        document.getElementById("humidity-text").innerHTML =  "Humidity: " + response.main.humidity;
      } else {
        console.error(xhttp.statusText);
      }
    }
  };
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
  xhttp.send();
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  longitude = position.coords.longitude;
});

$(function() { 
  GetWeather();
});


function TempConversion () {
  return temperature === currentTemp ? currentTemp = temperature * 1.8 + 32 : currentTemp = temperature;
}

currentTemp = temperature;
```

```css
* {
    font-family: roboto;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.aligner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 95vh;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main-container {
    background-color: beige;
    max-width: 50%;
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

.weather-info {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.weather-info li {
    margin: 8px 0px;
}

#skies-icon {
    margin: auto;
}

#weather-button {
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
    <body>
      <div class="aligner">
        <div class="main-container">
          <h1>Weather in your area: </h1>
          <div class="weather-info">
            <ul>
              <li id="skies-icon"></li>
              <li id="temperature-text"></li>
              <li id="city-text"></li>
              <li id="skies-text"></li>
              <li id="humidity-text"></li>
              <li><button id="weather-button" onclick="GetWeather()">GET YOUR WEATHER</button></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advanced for helping!

Comment: where do you get `undefined`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script worked fine for me. What I think is happening is that you are putting in bogus lat and long variables (need to do some input checking) this will return `undefined` for `response.main` and probably why you are getting `undefined`

I noticed the API will return `response.error` if there is one, so I suggest checking for that before you continue.

I would suggest adding some error handling like

```
if(response.error){
  console.error(`OH NO! ${response.error}`);
  return;
}
```

For example:

```js
var temperature;
var currentTemp;

function GetWeather(latitude, longitude) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", `https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}`, true);
  xhttp.onload = function(e) {
    if (xhttp.readyState === 4) {
      if (xhttp.status === 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        if (response.error) {
          console.error(`OH NO! ${response.error}`);
          return;
        }
        temperature = response.main.temp;
        document.getElementById("city-text").innerHTML = "City: " + response.name;
        document.getElementById("skies-text").innerHTML = "Skies: " + response.weather[0].main + " - " + response.weather[0].description;
        document.getElementById("skies-icon").innerHTML = "<img src='" + response.weather[0].icon + "'>";
        document.getElementById("temperature-text").innerHTML = "Temperature: " + temperature + "C";
        document.getElementById("humidity-text").innerHTML = "Humidity: " + response.main.humidity;
      } else {
        console.error(xhttp.statusText);
      }
    }
  };
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
  xhttp.send();
};

$(function() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    GetWeather(latitude, longitude);
  });
});


function TempConversion() {
  return temperature === currentTemp ? currentTemp = temperature * 1.8 + 32 : currentTemp = temperature;
}

currentTemp = temperature;
```

```css
* {
  font-family: roboto;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.aligner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 95vh;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main-container {
  background-color: beige;
  max-width: 50%;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.weather-info {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.weather-info li {
  margin: 8px 0px;
}

#skies-icon {
  margin: auto;
}

#weather-button {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aligner">
  <div class="main-container">
    <h1>Weather in your area: </h1>
    <div class="weather-info">
      <ul>
        <li id="skies-icon"></li>
        <li id="temperature-text"></li>
        <li id="city-text"></li>
        <li id="skies-text"></li>
        <li id="humidity-text"></li>
        <li><button id="weather-button" onclick="GetWeather()">GET YOUR WEATHER</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did as you said and added the error logging code. It does appear that I am sending variables with no value but I don't understand why since I have code to assign them to a new value. `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  longitude = position.coords.longitude;
});`

Comment: try to avoid using lat and long as global variables. Also try to avoid global variables always. They aren't getting set in time before GetWeather() is called (which is as soon as the DOM loads)

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how to set latitude and longitude so they are not globals. The sandboxing of StackOverflow won't allow location to be shared so you'll have to try it in your env to see it work

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! Just updated my code and it is working exactly how I wanted it to.